# Objected created in test database is not found by controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

This test clicks a link that hits `show_fretboard` in `static_pages_controller.rb`:

```
describe "StaticPages" do
  subject { page }
  let!(:key) { FactoryGirl.create(:key, user: user, name: 'C') }
  .
  .
  .
  describe "the fretBoard" do
    before { visit root_path }
    it 'should appear when clicked', js: true do
      puts key.name
      puts key.id
      puts Key.find_by(name: 'C').id
      click_link 'fretBoard-side-link'
      page.should have_selector("#fretboard-key-header", :text => "Showing Notes in the Key of")
    end
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

The test's failure shows this:

```
Run options: include {:line_numbers=>[141]}
C
9
9

An error occurred in an after hook
  NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
  occurred at /Users/user_name/rails_projects/my_project/app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:69:in `show_fretboard'
```

The key exists as it is outputting the key's name and ID. When `static_pages_controller.rb` tries to find the key, as seen here:

```
def show_fretboard
    @key = params[:key] || Key.find_by(name: 'C').id
```

This error is thrown:

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

Why is this query not finding the Key object with name 'C'?

**EDIT:** This post (http://justinleitgeb.com/rails/common-rails-testing-mistakes/) says that:

- Javascript-enabled tests in Capybara run in another thread
- Database elements (from factories, etc) you create in the test example won’t be visible in the server thread

It looks like this is my issue, so my question becomes, how can I use JS tests to test my ajax calls while still querying the database.

**EDIT:** Database cleaner setup:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  puts 'in database_cleaner.rb'
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

# source: http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/
end
```

Comment: Are you using something like `database_cleaner` or this [patch](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup) to share the database connection between your tests and the driver?

Comment: I am using database_cleaner because when I was not, I kept having issues of sequences being reused and throwing validation errors because of non-unique attributes.

Comment: Which strategy are you using with database_cleaner? Only truncation or deletion will work with a test using the Javascript driver.

Comment: I'm not really sure, to be honest. I don't think I spent much time setting it up, or if I'm even using it beyond installing the gem.

Comment: @ChrisGunther, I've added the database_cleaner setup I'm trying now, but it still isn't working. I included the source of the blog post that I got that setup from. I also set `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` in `spec_helper.rb`. The config is running when I boot up spork. Thanks again

Comment: this is a classic, basically everyone running integration tests is hitting this problem at some point in development. sucks big times. this is my solution for this problem https://gist.github.com/phoet/6683280#file-readme-md